# How to get preferences value from another controller

Tags: java, javafx

I'm quite new in javafx. I am now making an application which has a settings page. Now i want to implement that settings on all of my pages. How can i do that? I've tried to use resource bundle but I've read that the data on it cannot be changed. I've already use preferences and it works on a single controller. But i don't know how to call it in all of my controllers.

Comment: Just make a method in the controller that returns the data, and call it to retrieve the data... Hard to be more precise than that without seeing any code.

Comment: I can't. I need the data to remain even if i close my application.

Comment: Then you will probably need to save it in some file or database and retrieve it on startup.